# Handle large file with Stream in Scala

Tags: scala, fs2

I have a large csv file with users data. I have an endpoint that gets a user and should return a boolean indicating whether the user exists in the file or not.
To avoid running out of memory I read the file in streams and use `getLines` which is lazy.
This is my code:

```
  def readUsers(filePath: Path): IO[Seq[User]] = {
    Stream
      .eval(IO(scala.io.Source.fromFile(filePath.toFile)))
      .flatMap(source => Stream.fromIterator[IO](source.getLines(), 64))
      .map(line => line.split(",")
      .map(cols => User(cols(0), cols(1), cols(2), cols(3)))
      .compile
      .toList
  }

  def isUserExists(user: User, users: IO[Seq[User]]): IO[Boolean] =
    users.map(_.contains(user))
```

I assign `users` a value when the app starts:

```
val users = readUsers(filePath)
```

and send it to the `isUserExists` function whenever the endpoint is called.

My questions are:

1. Does the `toList` keep the entire file to the memory?
2. If so, how to avoid it? Should I remove the `toList` and iterate over each line in `isUserExists`?
3. When the content of the file changes, will it be reflected in the endpoint since the `users` is an IO value?

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. Iterator is used to read one by one, it does not load the whole file into memory. 3. I wouldn´t set my fire to myself for FS2, because I haven´t worked with it, but it should.

Comment: This almost sounds like maybe that csv file should become a sql database of some kind instead

Answer (score 2):

```
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.implicits._
import fs2._
import fs2.io.file.Files
import fs2.io.file.Path
import java.nio.file.{Path => JPath}

object SO20230802 {

  val givenUser: User = ???

  def readUsers(filePath: JPath): IO[Boolean] =
    Files[IO]
      .readAll(Path.fromNioPath(filePath))
      .through(text.utf8.decode)
      .through(text.lines)
      .map(_.split(","))
      .map {
        case Array(a, b, c, d) => User(a, b, c, d).some
        case _                 => None
      }
      .unNone
      .dropWhile(_ != givenUser)
      .take(1)
      .as(true)
      .lastOr(false)
      .compile
      .lastOrError

}
```

`fs2.io` will manage resource properly

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have another question, In my implementation it will read the file in http call. Can I use something like files watcher to avoid this? I want that the file will not be loaded to the memory, and that the API will return answer based on the latest file data.

Comment: There are two aspects here that you need to think about:

1. file changes (you can use `file.lastModified()`).

2. the different value for the `givenUser: User` got via API.

I would think about `Map[User, (DateTime, Boolean)]` wrapped into `Ref`, assuming you are working with typelevel stack

Comment: for further ideas more inputs needed about precedence and causation

Comment: But tracking changes in the file will help if I don't load it into memory anyway? That is, even if there are no changes I will still have to read the file again because it is not in memory.

Comment: Initially, was mentioned the file is huge and keeping it in the memory is not the case. So, my understanding is that we cache all the requests in the `Ref[Map[,]]`, and if file is changed we remove the cache and start caching again.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah.. your problem is that you are turning the stream into a concrete and complete list. To benefit from streaming you have to use streaming functions and references as much as possbile. I recommend `readUsers` returns a `fs2.Stream[IO, User]` and you start treating Streams as a "major" type that's used in signatures throughout your application. As you get more familiar with Streams it should feel more natural to use.

```scala
  import java.nio.file._
  case class User(name :String)
  import cats._
  import cats.effect._
  
  
  def readUsers(filePath: Path): fs2.Stream[IO, User] = {
    fs2.Stream
      .eval(IO(scala.io.Source.fromFile(filePath.toFile))) // please see fs2.io!!!
      .flatMap(source => fs2.Stream.fromIterator[IO](source.getLines()))
      .map(line => line.split(","))
      .map(cols => User(cols(0) /* simplified example, cols(1), cols(2), cols(3) */))
      // removed lines turning steam into a concrete thing.
  }

  def isUserExists(user: User, users: fs2.Stream[IO, User]): IO[Boolean] =
    userList
        .exists(_ == User("henry"))
        .last
        .compile
        .toList
        .map(_.flatten.headOption.getOrElse(false))

  val userList = fs2.Stream.fromIterator[IO](List(
    User("henry"),
    User("donald")
  ).toIterator)
  
  isUserExists(User("donald"), userList)
    .map { ans => println(s"Got this: $ans") }
    .unsafeRunSync()
```

In terms of examples, this doesn't really show off the great features of fs streams because exists() effectively drains the entire stream immediately. I'm not sure how the code is used but you want to focus on only traversing the stream once so repeated isUserExist calls doesn't necessarily fit the best usecase.